# Angular service-worker prevent caching of SSE calls

Tags: angular, server-sent-events, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I've got a PWA set up using angular (5.2.9) service-worker. The following is my configuration:

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [{
    "name": "app",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/index.html"
      ],
      "versionedFiles": [
        "/*.bundle.css",
        "/*.bundle.js",
        "/*.chunk.js"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**"
      ],
      "urls": [
        "https://fonts.googleapis.com/**",
        "https://fonts.gstatic.com/**"
      ]
    }
  }],
  "dataGroups": [{
    "name": "api-freshness",
    "urls": [
      "!/api/event"
    ],
    "cacheConfig": {
      "strategy": "freshness",
      "maxSize": 30,
      "maxAge": "20m",
      "timeout": "9s"
    }
  }]
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve under `dataGroups.urls[]` is to cache every fetch using network-first principle **except** calls to `/api/event`, which is a ServerSentEvents endpoint using a long-lived connection. Sadly, the setup above does *not* acheive this.

This endpoint is used on two central routes in my application, but listen for the same type of event calling for a data-refresh. Inspecting my app under DevTools `Application`>`Clear Storage`, I can tail the storage size as the client caches requests. It's all nice and minimal until I open a route using `api/event`. Then the cache suddenly jumps 3-4 Mb, and I'm guessing this is because it's a stream... ?

After caching the call, every call to `api/event` comes in two times, one from network and one from service-worker and the service-worker call is always pending. By closing the SSE connection, only the network call is canceled. The effect of this is that after navigating back and forth between the two routes using this endpoint a couple of times, it would seem that chrome runs out of available sockets - making further calls to any endpoint stuck in a *Pending* state, which in turn leaves my app in a useless state. :-(

Any input on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: No, I still haven't figured this out.

Answer (score 1):

I've read the code of generated `ngsw-worker.js` file, and found this line:

```
if (req.headers.has('ngsw-bypass') || /[?&]ngsw-bypass(?:[=&]|$)/i.test(requestUrlObj.search)) {
  return;
}
```

So I just changed my connection URL to this one:

```
this.sse = new EventSource(`${EVENTS_API}?accessToken=${token}&ngsw-bypass=true`);
```

And it helped, now my Angular app can connect to Server Sent Events API every time with no errors.

Comment: Can be found in the official documentation: https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#bypassing-the-service-worker

Answer (score -2):

if you want to prevent duplicate service worker call then please do few steps as below.

1. build your project production mode.
2. goto build folder (default is /dist)
3. open ngsw-worker.js file under /dist directory.
4. find  `onFetch(event) {` function
5. modify the onfetch function like below

   ```
   onFetch(event) {
   ```

   `/* your api endpouint url or domain url here*/`

   ```
   var blackListDomain=["www.xyz.com/api","www.abc.com/v2/api"];

   for (var i = 0; i < blackListDomain.length; i++) {
       if (event.request.url.indexOf(blackListDomain[i])>-1) {
            console.log("revent " + event.request.url);
           return;
       }
   }
   ```

**Hint**

[image]

Comment: This feels like modifying packages inside node_modules and thus something to avoid. It will break each time the project is built and is impossible to manage if built by a CI/CD system.

Comment: you don't need to modify inside of package.json. you need to modify in ngsw-worker.js file after angular build succeeded.   also your project is auto deployed into the server(CI/CD) in that case you can write few lines of code in NODE.js and you can execute it after angular build success.